# Busqueda avanzada con varios filtros

Tags: c#, webforms

Tengo el siguiente formulario en windows forms que consume un web service:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realizo la comparaciòn de 3 filtros, los cuales estàn quemados:

```
ExpresionLogica exLogica = new ExpresionLogica();

// primer comparador
ComparacionCaracter compCar = new ComparacionCaracter();
compCar.Argumento1 = textBoxValorCampo1Avanzada1.Text;
compCar.IdCampo = ((CampoCaracter)comboBoxCamposAvanzada1.SelectedItem).Id;
compCar.Operador = OperadoresAvanzada.IGUAL;

// segundo comparador
ComparacionCaracter compCar2 = new ComparacionCaracter();
compCar2.Argumento1 = textBoxValorCampo1Avanzada2.Text;
compCar2.IdCampo = ((CampoCaracter)comboBoxCamposAvanzada2.SelectedItem).Id;
compCar2.Operador = OperadoresAvanzada.IGUAL;

// tercer comparador
ComparacionCaracter compCar3 = new ComparacionCaracter();
compCar3.Argumento1 = textBoxValorCampo1Avanzada3.Text;
compCar3.IdCampo = ((CampoCaracter)comboBoxCamposAvanzada3.SelectedItem).Id;
compCar3.Operador = OperadoresAvanzada.IGUAL;

// expresion logica 1
// junto los dos primeros comparadores en una expresion logica, con el operador "Y"
ExpresionLogica exLogicaAuxiliar1 = new ExpresionLogica();
exLogicaAuxiliar1.Operador = OperadoresLogicos.Y;
exLogicaAuxiliar1.TerminoIzquierdo = compCar;
exLogicaAuxiliar1.TerminoDerecho = compCar2;

// expresion logica final
// luego junto la expresion lógica creada antes, con el otro comparador, con el operador "Y"
exLogica.Operador = OperadoresLogicos.Y;
exLogica.TerminoIzquierdo = exLogicaAuxiliar1;
exLogica.TerminoDerecho = compCar3;
bavRequest.Filtro = exLogica;
```

Entonces lo que tengo es la comparaciòn de los dos primeros y posteriormente comparo el resultado con el tercero.

Luego, realizo la bùsqueda hacia el webservice concatenando los filtros.

```
// Se llama a la búsqueda
bavResult = new BusquedaAvanzadaRes();
bavResult = scc.BusquedaAvanzada(guidRecAux, bavRequest);
```

Ahora, tengo un formulario web donde los combobox contienen opciones obtenidas desde el webservice, en los textbox se ingresarà un valor para poder realizar una comparaciòn utilizando las opciones de los combobox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo realizar una bùsqueda avanzada uniendo los filtros del formulario. Cabe mencionar que cada vez que se de clic en el botòn "+" se agregarà una nueva fila de filtros, por lo que no siempre serà el mismo nùmero de filtros a comparar.

¿Còmo se puede unir los filtros para realizar una bùsqueda avanzada? Es decir, concatenar los N filtros para enviar como una expresiòn al webservice.

Por ejemplo:

Si tuviese 5 filtros, tendrìa que comparar de dos en dos y el resultado de los 4 primeros con el quinto filtro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero cual es la pregunta?. Te sugiero que le des un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) a este sitio para veas como preguntar y asi se te pueda ayudar mas rapidamente.

Comment: ¿Còmo se puede unir los filtros para realizar una bùsqueda avanzada?

Comment: Como obtienes los campos de tu web y cual es el codigo de tu busqueda?

Comment: que valores podrian tomar los combos ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Combos del lado izquierdo toman informaciòn de una persona por ejemplo pasaporte, nombre, apellido... Combos del lado derecho operaciones aritmèicas

Comment: la unica forma de armar algo dinamico de esa forma es concatenando en un string y el resultado seria la query que ejecutas

Comment: En tu pregunta agrega un ejemplo de como esperas que sea tu consult, despues de obtener la seleccion de parametros.

Answer (score 0):

La unica forma de armar una consulta definiendo todo dinamico es por medio de un string, algo como ser

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE ";

List<string> filtros = new List<filtros>();
foreach(var item in lista)
{
   var combo1 = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("nombreCombo1");
   var combo2 = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("nombreCombo2");
   var TextBox1 = (TextBox)item.FindControl("nombreTextBox1");

   filtros.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", combo1.SelectedValue, combo2.SelectedValue, TextBox1.Text));
}
query += string.Join(" AND ", filtros);

comando.CommandText = query;
var reader = comando.ExecuteReader()
```

No se cual es el contenedor de esos controles, quizas sea un `Repeater` o un `ListView`, la idea es que puedas iterar los items y obtener el valor de cada linea, quizas puedas usar el `FindControl()` para acceder a cada control de la linea

Comment: @Christian solo con operadores? que quiere decir eso? con operadores contra que cosa? creo que deberias mirar [mcve] y dejar mas en claro lo que queres